# How did G-d make animals and how did they became living beings?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, animals, parashat-bereishit, creation

I read a couple of questions and answers that are related to mine, but I could not find any answer to my specific question.

The first human being was formed from the dust of the ground; this became the body of the human. Then afterwards became a living being/existence (nefesh chayah) after HaShem breathed in his nostrils the nishmat chayim.

But how were the other living beings/existences (nefesh chayah) - animals - formed (according to my comment below from the same dust of the earth) and were or how did they became living beings (were did they got there 'breath of life (nishmat chayim)' if G-d did not breathed it in their nostrils)?

Comment: Animals are also formed out of the ground, Bereshit 2:19, but the second part of the question still remains

Comment: Their breathing their last breaths (dying) in the same way; breathing their first breaths... well in the sense of breath, the ruach of men is identical with the ruach of animals (Kohelet 3:19); maybe it's the same with the nishmat. But i'm not sure if the proces of gaining the first breath was the same. The Source of both is HaShem Elohim, but breathing His Ruach in the Human or giving ruach to the animals could make a difference, but that's just a thought.

Comment: I rather think that animals and humans are made the same, but have different qualities or abilities; on the outline some creatures swim, others fly, humans think. But in each 'individual group' individuals may excell in some specific things; not all kind of birds or each one of its kind is exactly the same in appearance (looks) and deeds (outcome of inner qualities and abilities).

Comment: Maybe your right; then the difference between the human being and animals can be found in the part that the human being was made in or with the model (the image; the buildingplan) from Elohim and like/after/according to the resemblance of Elohim; meaning that the human being in its building has the qualities and abilities reflecting HaShem Elohim.

Comment: Set (Bereshit 5:3) then was like/after/according to the model of Adam, and was made in the resemblance of Adam; meaning that Sets 'building' was like (in the likeness of) that of Adam, and that his qualities and abilities reflecting Adams (see the change of the prifixes Bet & Kaf in the verse of Bereshit 1:26 to Kaf & Bet in the verse of Bereshit 5:3 ).

Comment: One more point i would like to make about what i wrote earlier is this: Kohelet 12:7 adds to the idea given in Kohelet 3:19 - refering to animals and the human being having one ruach and the fact they both die the same way (breathing their last breath out) - by stating that the dust shall return to dust, and that the ruach shall return to Elohim who gave it. In referce; Animals, based on these points, having gotten their ruach also of Elohim; thus their first breath that animated their eartly body (fro the dust) came from Him.

Answer (score 1):

According to The Ibn Ezra, the earth used its "inherent power" to bring forth all living things, including humans. Infact, his [commentary](http://www.js.emory.edu/BLUMENTHAL/GenIbnEzra.html) sounds, to me, a lot like evolution.

> Bereishit,11: Let the earth use its inherent power to produce plant
>   life on the earth...
>
> Bereishit,20: Let the waters use their inherent power to swarm forth
>   multitudes of living beings composed of elemental earth, water, air,
>   and fire...
>
> Bereishit,24: God said effortlessly, "Let the earth use its inherent
>   power to bring forth living beings composed of elemental earth, water,
>   air, and fire -- including humanity -- according to their kinds...

Comment: Thank you for your comment; Please take a look at the comments I posted. Maybe your comment fit with my idea.

Comment: the original hebrew would be useful to add here